# Django: One FormWizard for multiple models

Tags: django, django-forms, django-formwizard

Would it be possible/best practice to use 1 FormWizard for manipulating multiple models?

I've experimented with the FormWizard and have defined all the forms.  The page 'flow' itself works like a charm. However with all the checks that need to be done and Models that are manipulated it feels like I'm sticking code in the form's `__init__` and/or process_step() that really belongs in views.py. The docs even state: "Dont manipulate form data via process_step().

Testing a concept with everything in one view, thus using a last_submitted_page (the step equiv) it feels like I'm writing another formwizard.

Anybody been here before? Tips welcome.

Thanx a lot.

Regards,

Gerard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zooming out on the issue I decided to go for the FormWizard approach. I re-confirmed that code is easily placed in forms.py and that you can get your model info by using. the process_step().

GrtzG